# How can I locate all Mac OS X 'alias' files and find their target files (despite broken links)?

Tags: alias, macos

I've found some unexplained symbolic links on my HDD. Unfortunately, these links don't work -- i.e., clicking on it doesn't get me to the original file. The Finder shows them as "Alias" but they're not Mac OS Alias files.

So now I would like to find all symlinks on my HDD. Then for each one, search for the file that it once linked to, presumably on the same HDD. Then copy that file to the same subdirectory.

Roughly speaking, the pseudo-code solution I'm hoping for might be written as:

```
FIND all files (in Directory) type=SYMLINK. FOR each one, DO ..
      FIND referentFile (somewhere on the HDD)
      cp referentFile to (Subdirectory that contains the alias).
DONE.
```

Many thanks.

Comment: Thank you all for informative suggestions. I'm adding edit to OP, cuz I just figured out that I'm dealing with symlinks rather than aliases per se. (For some reason, they show up as aliases in finder.) Sorry if I wasted your time with wrong question.

Comment: I'm not sure how you'd figure out what file a symlink used to point to -- a symlink's target is just a unix path, and if there's no file at that path... what criteria can we use to find the original file?

Answer (score 4):

The first part of this question has an answer on [AskDifferent](https://apple.stackexchange.com/):

- [How to find all the aliases within a given file system?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/182980/how-to-find-all-the-aliases-within-a-given-file-system)

Here is the command to find aliases:

```bsh
mdfind kMDItemKind="Alias"
```

In general you can use the [mdfind](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/mdfind.1.html) (MetaData Find) command to (very) quickly search for files. From the man-pages:

> The **mdfind** command consults the central metadata store and returns a list of files that match the given metadata query. The query can be a string or a query expression.

So I wouldn't give up on OSX just yet. In fact, `mdfind` is one of the things I miss most about OSX when I'm on Linux.

Unfortunately the second part of this question was surprisingly more difficult to resolve. I found a few relevant StackExchange posts:

- [How to query target of all Finder aliases?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5084584/how-to-query-target-of-all-finder-aliases)
- [OS X terminal command to resolve path of an alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175094/os-x-terminal-command-to-resolve-path-of-an-alias)
- [How do I fix failed aliases?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2656/how-do-i-fix-failed-aliases)
- [Reading Alias files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2606255/reading-alias-files)

These led me to several potential solutions.

My favorite came from the blog post [Make Terminal Follow Aliases Like Symlinks](http://blog.warrenmoore.net/blog/2010/01/09/make-terminal-follow-aliases-like-symlinks/). It referenced [a small open-source C program called getTrueName.c](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/GalCohen/dotfiles/master/getTrueName.c). Here is the source code:

```c
// getTrueName.c
// 
// DESCRIPTION
//   Resolve HFS and HFS+ aliased files (and soft links), and return the
//   name of the "Original" or actual file. Directories have a "/"
//   appended. The error number returned is 255 on error, 0 if the file
//   was an alias, or 1 if the argument given was not an alias
// 
// BUILD INSTRUCTIONS
//   gcc-3.3 -o getTrueName -framework Carbon getTrueName.c 
//
//     Note: gcc version 4 reports the following warning
//     warning: pointer targets in passing argument 1 of 'FSPathMakeRef'
//       differ in signedness
//
// COPYRIGHT AND LICENSE
//   Copyright 2005 by Thos Davis. All rights reserved.
//   This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
//   modify it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as
//   published by the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the
//   License, or (at your option) any later version.
//
//   This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but
//   WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
//   MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the GNU
//   General Public License for more details.
//
//   You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public
//   License along with this program; if not, write to the Free
//   Software Foundation, Inc., 59 Temple Place, Suite 330, Boston,
//   MA 02111-1307 USA


#include <Carbon/Carbon.h> 
#define MAX_PATH_SIZE 1024
#define CHECK(rc,check_value) if ((check_value) != noErr) exit((rc))

int main ( int argc, char * argv[] ) 
  { 
    FSRef               fsRef; 
    Boolean             targetIsFolder; 
    Boolean             wasAliased; 
    UInt8               targetPath[MAX_PATH_SIZE+1]; 
    char *              marker;

    // if there are no arguments, go away
    if (argc < 2 ) exit(255); 

    CHECK( 255,
      FSPathMakeRef( argv[1], &fsRef, NULL ));

    CHECK( 1,
      FSResolveAliasFile( &fsRef, TRUE, &targetIsFolder, &wasAliased));

    CHECK( 255,
      FSRefMakePath( &fsRef, targetPath, MAX_PATH_SIZE)); 

    marker = targetIsFolder ? "/" : "" ;
    printf( "%s%s\n", targetPath, marker ); 

    exit( 1 - wasAliased );
  }
```

I downloaded this source code and compiled using the following command:

```bsh
gcc -o getTrueName -framework Carbon getTrueName.c
```

Of course I wanted to test it out. In order to avoid leaving the terminal I created an alias using the following commands:

```
user@host:~$ FULL_PATH_TO_TARGET_FILE=/tmp/alias-target

user@host:~$ echo "testing" > "${FULL_PATH_TO_TARGET_FILE}"

user@host:~$ osascript \
-e 'tell application "Finder"' \
-e "make new alias to file (posix file \"${FULL_PATH_TO_TARGET_FILE}\") at desktop" \
-e 'end tell'

alias file alias-target of folder Desktop of folder user of folder Users of disk MacHD
```

Then I verified the Alias using the `getTrueName` program:

```
user@host:~$ ./getTrueName ~/Desktop/alias-target

/tmp/alias-target
```

Victory!

The blog post [Stupid Mac OS X Tricks: Resolving Aliases](http://pudge.net/glob/2003/02/useperl-10437.html) also looks like it might have a solution. It contained the following Perl script:

```perl
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use Mac::Errors;
use Mac::Files;
use Mac::Resources;

my $path = '/Users/pudge/Desktop/some alias';
my $res  = FSpOpenResFile($path, 0) or die $Mac::Errors::MacError;
# get resource by index; get first "alis" resource
my $alis = GetIndResource('alis', 1) or die $Mac::Errors::MacError;
my $link = ResolveAlias($alis);
print $link;
```

I didn't have the required libraries and I didn't feel like installing a bunch of stuff, so I gave up on this one.

I also found the [mac_alias](http://mac-alias.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), which seemed promising. I spent 5 or 10 minutes messing around with it, but wasn't able to figure out how to resolve an alias target.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This works great.

I'd also like to know how to find the original referent file, given that the alias no longer points to it.

There's tons of these broken alias links that need to be resolved. I'd like to use one script that finds all aliases and, for each one, finds its referent.

Is that possible? Thanks.

Comment: @ericlindellnyc Ok, I think I found what you're looking for. I included links to all of my references - hopefully it's not too disorganized. Let me know what you think.

Answer (score 0):

I might have figured out how to locate referent files for symlinks that are broken.

[Btw, I'm the OP -- couldn't find original loginfo, so I signed up anew.]

Use a duplicate file finder like dupeGuru. Set it to 
  o  Search entire directory/drives containing symlinks and referents.
  o  Mix files of different types.
  o  Inexact matches are okay (i.e., certainty-level around 80%).
  o  Match filename only (not content or entire directory).

This will turn up many false positives, but it will include symlinks and their referents (broken or intact).